# Is there a reason to use C language pointers like this &(*foo)?

Tags: c, pointers

I use to code pointers like this when I need to change the original memory address of a pointer.

Example:

```
static void get_line_func(struct data_s *data,
                                char **begin)
{
    data->slot_number = strsep(&(*(begin)), "/");
    data->protocol = *begin;
    strsep(&(*begin), ">");
    data->service_name = strsep(&(*begin), "\n");
}
```

I mean, isn't `&(*foo) == foo`?

Comment: It will crash in the function rather than in strsep if you pass a null pointer.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean Not necessarily. GCC & clang no-op `&*` even at `-O0`.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean not in C, only in   .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no reason to do that directly. However, the combination can arise in machine-generated code (such as the expansion of a preprocessor macro).

For instance, suppose we have a macro `do_something_to(obj)` which expects the argument expression `obj` to designate an object. Suppose somewhere in its expansion, this macro takes the address of the object using `&(obj)`.   Now suppose we would like to apply the macro to an object which we only hold via a pointer `ptr`. To designate the object, we must use the expression `*ptr` so that we use the macro as `do_something_to(*ptr)`. That of course means that`&(*ptr)` now occurs in the program.

The status of the expression `&*ptr` has changed over the years. I seem to remember that in the ANSI C 89 / ISO C90 dialect, the expression produced undefined behavior if `ptr` was an invalid pointer.

In ISO C11 the following is spelled out (and I believe nearly the same text is in C99), requiring `&*` not to dereference the pointer: *"if the  operand [of the address-of unary `&` operator] is the result of a unary `*` operator,
neither that operator nor the `&` operator is evaluated and the result is as  if both were
omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply and the  result is not an lvalue"*.  Thus in the modern C dialect, the expression `&*ptr` doesn't dereference `ptr`, hence has defined behavior even if that value is null.

What does that mean? "constraints still apply" basically means that it still has to type check. Just because `&*P` doesn't dereference `P` doesn't mean that `P` can be a `double` or a `struct`; it has to be a pointer.

The "result is not an lvalue" part is potentially useful. If we have a pointer `P` which is an value, if we wrap it in the expression `&*P`, we obtain the same pointer value as a non-lvalue. There are other ways to obtain the value of `P` as a non-lvalue, but `&*P` is a "code golfed" solution to the problem requiring only two characters, and having the property that it will remain correct even if `P` changes from one pointer type to another.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct - that sentence doesn't exist in C89, but does in C99. C89 only says that dereferencing an invalid value with `*` will cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: **Erratum:** an earlier version of this answer incorrectly said that `&*ptr` doesn't **use** the value of `ptr` so that `ptr` may be invalid. This is not the case; it uses the value as much as the primary expression `ptr` does; but doesn't **dereference** `ptr`, allowing it to be null.

Comment: Nice answer. I'd change "evaluate" to "dereference" in the 5th paragraph (P will be evaluated, just not dereferenced).

Comment: @RicardoMassaro Thanks; that's should have been part of the earlier correction.